# Error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

I am new to developing field, and I have encountered an error while creating a trigger.Could anyone please figure out what is the error?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_feedback_dashboard
AFTER INSERT
ON tblcustomfeedback FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE averageScore float default 0;
DECLARE avgscore float default 0;
DECLARE IdCount float default 0;

SELECT SUM(avg_score) into avgscore, COUNT(Id) into count FROM tblcustomfeedback  WHERE feedbackDate = NOW() ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1;

SET averageScore  =avgscore;
SET IdCount  =  count;

IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tblfeedbackdashbd WHERE Date=CURDATE()) = 0 
THEN
 INSERT INTO tblfeedbackdashbd(AverageScoresAday ,Date)     VALUES(averageScore/IdCount,CURDATE());
ELSE   
 UPDATE tblfeedbackdashbd SET AverageScoresAday=averageScore/IdCount  WHERE   Date=CURDATE();
END IF;
END $$
```

The error encountered is,

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'COUNT(Id) into count FROM tblcustomfeedback  WHERE
>   feedbackDate = NOW() ORDER BY' at line 11

Comment: you should use \`count\`  (with backticks) as count is a MySQL reserve word or may change the variable name to some other value

Comment: have changed the variable name..still no change in the error

Comment: @NawazSohail `COUNT` is not reserved (but I agree should not be used as a column or variable name.)

Comment: Only one `INTO` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is not:

```
SELECT id INTO @x, data INTO @y ...
```

but it is:

```
SELECT id, data INTO @x, @y ...
```

Use:

```
SELECT SUM(avg_score), COUNT(Id)
  INTO averageScore, IdCount
FROM ... ;
```

Comment: wow..thats it.Thank you so much for saving my time.

Answer (score 1):

You are working much too hard.  A single statement does all the work:

```
INSERT INTO  tblfeedbackdashbd (AverageScoresAday, Date)
    SELECT  SUM(avg_score) / COUNT(*),
            CURDATE()
        FROM  tblcustomfeedback
        WHERE  feedbackDate = NOW()   -- ??
        ORDER BY  Id DESC
        LIMIT  1
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        AverageScoresAday = (SUM(avg_score) + AverageScoresAday) / COUNT(*);
```

I assume you have `UNIQUE(Date)`

`COUNT(Id)` should probably be `COUNT(*)`.

This is probably *not* what you wanted:  `WHERE  feedbackDate = NOW()`

[*Reference*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html);
[*Reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/866/insert/2923/insert-on-duplicate-key-update#t=201611011936002376286)

Comment: I am getting a syntax error while using this query.

Comment: And the full text of the syntax error is ___?  Please note that, when it says "near ...", it is usually pointing exactly at or after the offending token.

Comment: I may have fixed the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments..the syntax error has gone..but,what does this 'q' stands for??

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like a typo.  Maybe it is fixed now.  Suggest you read the manual on IODKU, I may have goofed in some other way, too.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing u again..have tried that too..but your query is inserting 1 row in "tblfeedbackdashbd" for each entry in "tblcustomfeedback"..I just need to update the  "AverageScoresAday" value for the same row in table "tblfeedbackdashbd"

Comment: Actually,my first  code is working in that way..but the problem is that the last entered value in tblcustomfeedback is not getting computed.The other part is working fine.your code is also not capturing the last entry in "tblcustomfeedback".Do u have any suggestion??

Comment: I may be getting lost in the semantics of the columns.  I made another change.

Comment: Does my solution work 'better' than the 'approved' answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `count` variable first,
add `DECLARE count INT 0;` right after `BEGIN`

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.But the error still persists.Is there anything wrong with that select query??

Comment: I have also declared count as a variable..still showing the error